# Scope of Variables in a While Loop

Tags: java, while-loop

```
int i = 1;
        while(i == 1) {
            if (answerHold.equals(generate)) {
                qgCharacter();
                i++;
            } else if (answerHold.equals(create)) {
                qcCharacter();
                i++;
            }
        }
```

The above code keeps running until a desired value is entered.

How would I maintain the accessibility of the variable inside of the while loop, instead of the variable having to be outside of the loop?

Would using a different loop make more in sense in this situation?

Comment: What variable are you talking about?

Comment: I'm talking about variable i

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the "break" keyword instead of changing the value of "i".

```
    while(true) {
        if (answerHold.equals(generate)) {
            qgCharacter();
            break;
        } else if (answerHold.equals(create)) {
            qcCharacter();
            break;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Not really, `i` can only be 2 if the loop ever terminates.

Comment: This just terminates the program. I need something that will keep asking until the desire is met.

Answer (score 1):

The following construct would make more sense in my opinion. Without a variable!

```
while (true) {
      if (answerHold.equals(generate)) {
                qgCharacter();
                break;
      } else if (answerHold.equals(create)) {
                qcCharacter();
                break;
      }
}
```

Comment: If someone enters a value other than what is desired the program terminates I want it too continue asking until the desire is met.

Comment: This code does exactly the same as the code you posted.

Comment: Thank you, this bit of code works I would accept yours but it only allows me to do one and the other guy entered it faster.